# Disable or enable checkbox, based on value in table

Tags: php

If $partner has the value No, I want to disable the checkbox checkPartner 
If $partner has the value Yes, I want to enable the checkbox checkPartner 

Grtz Benny

```
 <?php 

            $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Partner, VIP FROM event WHERE eventID = ".$row['eventID']." ");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))  

                        $partner = $row['Partner'];

                            if ($partner = 'No') {

                            }
            ?>


                <form action="" method="post" name="RegisterForm1" id="RegisterForm1">
                <h6>Partner :<input type="checkbox" name="checkPartner"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add the attribute 'disabled' to the html-element 'input'.
To do that based on a condition - in your case - it would be something like this.

```
<?php
// inside your while-loop

$disabled = '';  // default
if ($partner == 'No') { // check the double == here!
    $disabled = "disabled";
}
?>

// then add that string-var to the html-element
<input type="checkbox" name="checkPartner" <?php echo $disabled ?>/>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, this was what was looking for !